# For a divisor $D$ on a smooth curve $X$, what's the coker of the natural map $(\Omega^1_{X/k})^{\otimes m}\rightarrow\Omega^1_{X/k}(D)^{\otimes m}$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field, and $X/k$ a smooth curve.

Let $D = P_1 + P_2 + \cdots + P_r$ be a reduced effective divisor. The paper I'm reading speaks of the "canonical exact sequence"
$$0\rightarrow(\Omega^1_{X/k})^{\otimes m}\rightarrow\Omega^1_{X/k}(D)^{\otimes m}\rightarrow\bigoplus_i N_{P_i}^{\otimes m-1}\rightarrow 0$$
where they say $N_{P_i} := T^*_{X,P_i}$.

Unfortunately, they don't define $T^*_{X,P_i}$ either, so now I'm asking the question here: Is $T^*_{X,P_i}$ or $N_{P_i}$ common notation for something? (and why is it the cokernel of the map?)

For simplicity, we can consider the case $r = 1$. Then the cokernel should be supported on the single point $P_1$, and hence is just a skyscraper sheaf on $P_1$. The first two terms of the sequence should locally look like:
$$0\rightarrow (k[[t]]dt)^{\otimes m}\longrightarrow (k[[t]]\frac{dt}{t})^{\otimes m}$$
given by sending $(dt)^{\otimes m}\mapsto (dt)^{\otimes m}$. The right term then is the free $k[[t]]$-module of rank 1 generated by $\frac{dt}{t}^{\otimes m}$, and hence the cokernel should be generated as a $k[[t]]$-module by the single element $\frac{dt}{t}^{\otimes m}$ with the single relation $t^m\frac{dt}{t}^{\otimes m} = 0$. Ie, the cokernel should be isomorphic to $k[[t]]/(t^m)$.

Is this wrong? I don't really see how to interpret $k[[t]]/(t^m)$ as the $(m-1)$th tensor power of any cotangent space...  (assuming thats what $T^*_{X,P_1}$ means...)

Comment: My guess for $T_{X,P_i}^*$ is the cotangent space.

Comment: @Quasicoherent but isn't that just $\Omega^1$? Why $T^*$?

Comment: Yes, I guess it's the stalk of the sheaf $\Omega^1$ at the point $P_i$.  I mostly suggested it because this notation is often used for the cotangent space; (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cotangent_space#Formal_definitions)), for example.  $T_X$ is often used to denote the tangent sheaf  (or bundle), especially in differential geometry, and $T_X^*$ (its dual) is the cotangent sheaf (or bundle).  Could you link the paper to which you refer?

Comment: @Quasicoherent This is after the lemma on page 58 of https://perso.univ-rennes1.fr/matthieu.romagny/articles/champs_de_Hurwitz.pdf